# Convert map key from collection to double - java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, List<Double>>` and from this I want to get a SORTED `Map<String, Double>` where the keys in both maps are the same but the values in the second map are the averages of the values from the first map and then sorted. I’ve tried:

```
public class ListComparator implements Comparator<List<Double>> {
    public int compare(List<Double> lhs, List<Double>rhs){
        Double lhs_sum = lhs.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).sum()/lhs.size();
        Double rhs_sum = rhs.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).sum()/rhs.size();
        return lhs_sum.compareTo(rhs_sum);
    }
}
```

And then in main():

```
ListComparator listComparator = new ListComparator();
infoMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(listComparator))
                .limit(15).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But this prints out the key and, it appears, an array of varying number of doubles (should be one double only) that are not sorted. What step am I missing? 
Thanks

Comment: "averages of the keys", you mean "average of the _values_"?

Comment: yes, my bad, editing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only comparing, but I didn't see where you put the average to the output.

Try this:

```
infoMap.entrySet().stream()
       .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
                                   e.getValue().stream()
                                    .mapToDouble(d -> d).average()
                                    .orElse(0d)))
       .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Entry::getValue))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, 
                                (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

So you see, the first step is convert each entry to a `SimpleEntry<String, Double>` where value is the average of the list.

The second step is sort those mapped entries by `Entry::getValue`

Then finally, collect them back to a new `Map<String, Double>`

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction, thanks but the sorted bit is greyed out in Intellij and on hovering it pops up that the sorted call is redundant and the subsequent toMap call doesn't depend on the sort order. The resulting map is also not sorted,

Comment: called your sorted() on the resulting map from the one created above and then it works. thanks again

Comment: Oh forgot the sorted requirement. See my updated answer. Should use LinkedHashMap to retain insert order