# Sorting and Grouping Multi-field Objects

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have `List<MyObjects>` with 4 fields:

```
String fieldText;
double fieldDoubleOne;
double fieldDoubleTwo;
double fieldDoubleThree;
```

What would be the best (Java-8) way of collecting and printing out the list, sorted according to Average(fieldDoubleOne) so that the console output looks something like:
fieldText → Average(fieldDoubleOne) → Average(fieldDoubleTwo) → Average(fieldDoubleThree) 
Assume public getters for all fields. For one double field, I had, [from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919967/convert-map-key-from-collection-to-double-java):

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> groupByFieldText = myObjectList.stream().collect(groupingBy(MyObject::getFieldText));
Map<String, Double> averageMap =   groupByFieldText.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().stream()
                        .mapToDouble(d -> d.getDoubleOne()).average()
                        .orElse(0d)))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
averageMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble((Map.Entry::getValue)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What does "sorted according to Average(fieldDoubleOne)" mean?

Comment: There are a small number of distinct values for fieldText compared to the number of objects. So the objects are grouped by fieldText and displayed in sorted order of Average(fieldDoubleOne) while also displaying Average(fieldDoubleTwo) and Average(fieldDoubleThree). So think of fieldText as countryName for e.g and fieldDoubleOne as lifeExpectancy, etc

Comment: In your code, the second call to `sorted` (when streaming `averageMap`) is redundant - the map is already sorted by the same `Comparator` at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sort the entries instead of mapping their value to `double`, like that:

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> sortedByAverageOne = groupByFieldText.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> average(e, MyObject::getDoubleOne)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Note that if you have a lot of entries, it won't be very efficient because it calls `average` for *every* comparison.

Then, having such a sorted map you print it as follows:

```
sortedByAverageOne.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> String.format(
                "%s → %f → %f → %f",
                e.getKey(),
                average(e, MyObject::getDoubleOne),
                average(e, MyObject::getDoubleTwo),
                average(e, MyObject::getDoubleThree)
        ))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Finally, `average` is defined as:

```
private static double average(Map.Entry<String, List<MyObject>> entry, ToDoubleFunction<MyObject> getter) {
    return average(entry.getValue(), getter);
}

private static double average(List<MyObject> list, ToDoubleFunction<MyObject> getter) {
    return list.stream().mapToDouble(getter).average().orElse(0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help but getting a couple of errors (Intellij): 

`.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> average(e, MyObject::getDoubleOne)))`
hover on average: cannot resolve method ‘average<lambda expression>’
hover on e, MyObject: cannot resolve method ‘average(<lambda parameter>, <method reference>)

`toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,`
non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I tested it before posting, and it worked. Make sure you included all the code pieces, and in the right way. For example, if you put the `average` methods in a different place than the `Stream`-based code, you need to qualify the call to this method (so if you put it in `MyObjects` class, call `MyObjects.average()`).

Comment: there was just one small thing missing in the sorted map, should have been: `average(e.getValue(), MyObject::getDoubleOne)` many thanks